# Really Low SWR Reading On PMR

Tags: swr-meter

I spoke to a friend about what antennas I was using for PMR and the frequency range on them was only set to 170-430Mhz he said it could lead to a high SWR, So I decided to test it out for safety reasons I tried a few tests within the frequency range and they were reading 1.2 I then tried 446 and the needle didn't even move is this bad? 
P.s. I'm pretty new in this field.

Comment: Welcome! Does the radio or the meter show the power output from the radio?

Comment: It might help us to help you if you ID'ed the radio and the antenna.

Comment: [Is this the PMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_mobile_radio) that you mean?

Answer (score 1):

A low SWR is desirable and nothing to be concerned about. Any antenna operated at its design frequency should present a very low SWR.